# How do I set width(100%) the same as it's parent without using a string in React Native?

Tags: css, string, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am trying to get the `cropWidth` to be the same width as it's parent, but when I use a string I get this error: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. Here is the code:

```
<RkCard style={{width:'80%',  marginLeft: 40,  marginBottom: 50, backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5', position:'relative',  shadowColor: 'black', shadowOffset: {width: 10, height: 10}, shadowOpacity: 1, shadowRadius: 2, elevation: 5}}>
       <ImageZoom cropWidth={'100%'} <-- string here, error is thrown
                  cropHeight={300}
                  imageWidth={300}
                  imageHeight={300}
                  style={{left: 0, alignSelf:'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor:'#D3D3D3',}}>
         <FastImage rkCardImg source={{uri:`https://www.example.com/profiles/uploads/${item.images}`,
         headers:{ Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
         priority: FastImage.priority.high,
          }}
           resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
           style={{width: '100%', height: 300, left: 0, alignSelf:'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}/>

        </ImageZoom>
        </RkCard>
```

If I use an integer then the error goes away so it might only accept those. Is there a way I can set the width the same as it's parent with a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compute it yourself before the `return`.  For example:

```
let width = Dimensions.get('window').width * .8;
```

and then use that value in your `RkCard` and `cropWidth`, e.g.:

```
<RkCard style={{width,  marginLeft: 40,  marginBottom: 50, backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5', position:'relative',  shadowColor: 'black', shadowOffset: {width: 10, height: 10}, shadowOpacity: 1, shadowRadius: 2, elevation: 5}}>
   <ImageZoom cropWidth={width}
```

BTW, the problem is not a React Native style issue, it's how `ImageZoom` is written.

Comment: Thank you so much! I felt that doing it before the `return` was just an extra step so I just took the equation and inserted it into `cropWidth`. And yes, `ImageZoom` is very weird. Thank you again!